# Locking down RAD Studio internal browser security

Tags: security, delphi, browser, delphi-2009

I use Firefox as my web browser, mostly for access to add-ins such as Flashblock and No-script. I noticed yesterday that the RAD Studio internal browser used for the Welcome Page etc has scripting and Active X etc enabled. Is there a way to disable scripting, or better still, block all access to non-local sources in the built-in browser?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Delphi IDE uses an embedded Internet Explorer as browser.

If you lock down Internet Explorer, you will lock down the Delphi IDE browser as well.

Note that parts of welcome page in the Delphi IDE need JavaScript.

But you can replace that page if you need to.

--jeroen

Comment: This works. IE8 is installed but 'hidden'. RAD Studio browser reports as IE7 but disabling scripting in IE8 works. Cheers.